# HiveQL - Extract the value of Sibling node

Tags: xml, xpath, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a XML blob (as shown below) store in a hive log table.

```
<user>
    <uid>1424324325</uid>
    <attribs>
        <field>
        ...
        </field>
        <field>
            <name>first</name>
            <value>John</value>
        </field>
        <field>
        ...
        </field>
        <field>
            <name>last</name>
            <value>Doe</value>
        </field>
        <field>
        ...
        </field>
    </attribs>
</user>
```

Each row in the hive table would have information about different users and I want to extract the values of uid, first name and last name.

```
1424324325  John    Doe
1424435463  Jane    Smith
```

Extracting uid value is pretty simple. However, I am getting stumped trying to extract the first name & last name. The problem is about identifying the first name & last name pair and extracting the value.

I tried to extract the first name & last name as shown below but I got an error saying this is an invalid expression.

```
SELECT uid, fn, ln
FROM log_table
LATERAL VIEW explode(xpath(logs['users_updates'], '/user/uid/text()')) uids as uid
LATERAL VIEW explode(xpath(logs['users_updates'], '/user/attribs/field/name/text()="first"/../value/text()')) fns as fn
LATERAL VIEW explode(xpath(logs['users_updates'], '/user/attribs/field/name/text()="last"/../value/text()')) lns as ln;
```

I thought of using a hard-coded expression for the field node as shown below but the problem is that different records will have the first name and last name values in different locations.

```
LATERAL VIEW explode(xpath(logs['users_updates'], '/user/attribs/field[5]/value/text()')) fns as fn
```

When I try to extract first name as shown below, the result is empty.

```
LATERAL VIEW explode(xpath(logs['users_updates'], '/users/attribs/field/name/[text()="last"]/following-sibling::value[1]/text()')) fns as fn
```

How can I extract the information I want like below?

```
1424324325  John    Doe
1424435463  Jane    Smith
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XPath should give you the correct result. Your syntax was incorrect (a predicate (i.e. everything in brackets) needs to be with an element, but you just did a child step using `/`).

```
/users/attribs/field[name = "first"]/value/string()
```

Furthermore, some points to improve your query:

- You do not have to use `text()` when comparing node values, it will be done automatically and it is quite likely faster
- You almost always want to use `string()` over `text()`
- I rewrote the query, I think this is much simpler and cleaner, because it basically says "Give me the value node, which has a name node with the value *first*". Your attempt using following-sibling or the parent are also valid, I just think this one is simpler to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your query worked as expected only if I use text() instead of string(). string() returned me no results.

Comment: Is it possible to check for both the name and value data like this? /users/attribs/field[name = "first" and value = "John"]